# I am trying to change button colour in category file but there is no idea for me?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicolor

This is the code to convert hexadecimal to rgb. It's working properly.

```
 #import "UIButton+ButtonClr.h"

@implementation UIButton (ButtonClr)
- (UIColor *)colorFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString {
    unsigned rgbValue = 0;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
    [scanner setScanLocation:1]; /// bypass '#' character///
    [scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0 alpha:1.0];

}
-(void)btnclr
{
    UIButton *set1;//i tried many methods here but no use please provide some help full method


}
///set1.backgroundcolor=[self colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400" ];///here i am used this for changing the color but not working.
```

Comment: What is the question? Whether or not there is an idea for you? What kind of idea? Your title doesn't make sense, so it is difficult to see what is the question if there is any at all.

Comment: @anthon OK will take care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UIColor+HexColor.h**

```
@interface UIColor (HexColor)
// send hex color codes array and it will return UIColor
+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexArray:(NSString *) color;
@end
```

**UIColor+HexColor.m**

```
 + (UIColor *)colorWithHexArray:(NSString *) color
        {
            @try {
                NSMutableArray * rgbColorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


                    NSString * colorArray1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",color];

                    NSString *cString = [[colorArray1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] uppercaseString];


                    // String empty then show clear color
                    if ([cString length]==0) return [UIColor clearColor];


                    // String should be 6 or 8 characters
                    if ([cString length] < 6) return [UIColor grayColor];

                    // strip 0X if it appears
                    if ([cString hasPrefix:@"0X"]) cString = [cString substringFromIndex:2];

                    // # replace with blank space
                    if ([cString hasPrefix:@"#"]) cString = [cString substringFromIndex:1];


                    if ([cString length] != 6) return  [UIColor grayColor];

                    // Separate into r, g, b substrings
                    NSRange range;
                    range.location = 0;
                    range.length = 2;
                    NSString *rString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

                    range.location = 2;
                    NSString *gString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

                    range.location = 4;
                    NSString *bString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

                    // Scan values
                    unsigned int r, g, b;
                    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];
                    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];
                    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];

                    UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) r / 255.0f)
                                                      green:((float) g / 255.0f)
                                                       blue:((float) b / 255.0f)
                                                      alpha:1.0f];

                    [rgbColorArray addObject:color];
                    return [rgbColorArray objectAtIndex:0];
                }

                return [UIColor clearColor];
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"Exception %@",exception);
            }
            @finally {

            }
            return [UIColor clearColor];
        }
```

calling that category method as follows:

```
set1.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithHexArray:@"#ff2323"];
```

I hope it will solved your problem :)

Comment: this parameter is an array how can i send as a string [UIColor colorWithHexArray:@"#ff2323"];

Comment: send like this @[@"ff2323"], it just make provision for in future if we want to show gradient color then will update some code. so for now you just pass it in array

Comment: Hey I have update my answer as per your requirement, it will take string argument now, just check and let me know is it working or not

Comment: Kishore if its working at you can you please accept and vote my answer

Comment: this the uicolour category but i am asking for button, is there any idea

Comment: @kishore you need to set background color to button which is hex so it must to you will write category on uicolor not on button. If you go for button category then it will be more complicated as well as not in as per apple standard. So my suggestion you will go with uicolor category as like my answer

Comment: yes now i am understood there is now way to use category button and i am used the (colorFromHexString) method its so easy.from you i am under stand there is now way to do in uibutton category thanks

Comment: If it is helpful for you please vote it so it will helpful for  other guys also